# OutOfMemoryError with ArrayList in Android Application

Tags: java, android, arraylist, while-loop, out-of-memory

In a activy I have written code that works correctly.

But now I have added a method to this activity with the following code:

```
    private void obtenerDatosReuniones(){

    try {

        int j=0;

        String aux = jsonReuniones.getString("nombres");

        String aux2 = null;

        aux2 = aux.replace("[", "");

        aux2= aux2.replace("]", "");

        String [] campos = aux2.split(",");

        while(j<campos.length){

            nombres_reuniones.add(campos[j]);

        }
```

the type of nombres_reunones is ArrayList

When I run the application appears out the following error on line nombres_reuniones.add (campos [j]):

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your loop:

```
while(j<campos.length){
    nombres_reuniones.add(campos[j]);
}
```

How do you anticipate that ever finishing? You don't modify `j`. Given that you don't make any change to `j` after declaring it and assigning it a value of `0` right at the start, it would be *much* clearer as:

```
for (int j = 0; j < campos.length; j++) {
    nombres_reuniones.add(campos[j]);
}
```

Or better:

```
for (String item : campos) {
    nombres_reuniones.add(item);
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
nombres_reunions.addAll(Arrays.asList(campos));
```

Additionally, your earlier code can be simpler. Look at this:

```
String aux2 = null;
aux2 = aux.replace("[", "");
aux2= aux2.replace("]", "");
```

Why bother assigning `aux2` an initial value of `null` which you then immediately overwrite? Additionally, you can easily chain the method calls. It would be neater as:

```
String aux2 = aux.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

And in fact, you can just chain the whole of the string manipulation together from start to finish:

```
String[] campos = jsonReuniones.getString("nombres")
                               .replace("[", "")
                               .replace("]", "")
                               .split(",");
nombres_reunions.addAll(Arrays.asList(campos));
```

(I'd stop there, rather than inlining even that expression...)

Answer (score 3):

You're not advancing the loop:

```
while (j < campos.length) {
    nombres_reuniones.add(campos[j]);
    j++; // without this, you'll loop forever!
}
```

What's happening is that you're adding an infinite amount of "campos" to the `ArrayList`, exhausting all the memory available to your program in the process.

Remember: a loop's condition must be `false` at some point for the loop to end. If you forget to advance the loop (in this case, by incrementing the `j` variable) the condition will always be `true` and the loop will never exit, therefore creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the value of `j` hence `j` is always `0`  and always smaller than `campos.length`